# Xmonad: Workspace-specific resolution

Tags: display-resolution, workspaces, xrandr, xmonad

I am using Xmonad as my window manager on Ubuntu 16.04. I use a 4k display, but a few applications need to be displayed at 1080p to appear correctly. I would like to store these applications in a specific workspace and then use a different resolution when on that workspace.

How can I make a specific Xmonad workspace use a different monitor resolution? Does Xmonad have a hook for this I can connect with a `xrandr` script, or is there a better strategy? I have looked through the documentation to try to find an answer, but I am struggling as I have no Haskell knowledge.